# Gensim Word2Vec Vocabulary: Unclear output

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-mining, gensim, word2vec

I'm starting to get familiar with Word2Vec, but I'm struggeling with a problem and coudln't find something similar...
I want to use gensims Word2Vec on an imported PDF document (a book). To import I used PyPDF2 and stored the whole book into a list. Furthermore, I used gensims simple_preprocess in order to preprocess the data. This worked so far, I got the following output:

```py
text=['schottky','diode','semiconductors',...]
```

So then I tried to use the Word2Vec:

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model=Word2Vec(text, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
words=list(model.wv.vocab)
```

but the output was like this:

```py
print(words)
['c','h','t','k','d',...]
```

I expected also the same words as in the text list and not just some characters. When I tried to find relations between words (e.g. 'schottky' and 'diode') I got the error-message that none of these words is included in the vocabulary.

My first thought was that the import is wrong, but I got the same result with textract instead of PyPDF2.

Does someone know what's the problem? Thanks for your help!

Appendix:

Importing the book

content_text=[]
number_of_inputs=len(os.listdir(path))

```
    file_to_open=path
open_file=open(file_to_open,'rb')
read_pdf=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_file)
number_of_pages=read_pdf.getNumPages()
page_content=""
for page_number in range(number_of_pages):
    page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)
    page_content += page.extractText()
content_text.append(page_content)
```

Comment: The corpus need to be a list of list of words as suggested by @Vivek in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Word2Vec` requires as its `sentences` parameter a training corpus that is:

- an iterable sequence (such as a list)
- where each item is itself a list of string-tokens

If you supply just a list-of-strings, each string is seen as a list-of-one-character-strings, resulting in all the one-letter words you're seeing.

So, use a list-of-lists-of-words, more like:

```
[
 ['schottky','diode','semiconductors'],
]
```

(Note also that you generally won't get interesting `Word2Vec` results on tiny toy-sized data sets of just a few texts and just dozens to hundreds of words. You need many thousands of unique words, across many dozens of contrasting examples of each word, to induce the useful word-vector arrangements that `Word2Vec` is known for.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`text=['schottky','diode','semiconductors']`

Use this 
`text=[['schottky','diode','semiconductors']]`

More info: [Gensim word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)